# What to do if my internet connection drops during the exam?

Tags: exams, online-learning

Next week I will start having online exams. One of the rules is that the camera must stay on during the whole time. Unfortunately, my internet connection will occasionally drop. This will happen rarely (maybe a few times a day) and will last from one to a few minutes. I am very worried that if this happens during the exam the professor may be suspicious. What can I do to assure him I'm not cheating?

Comment: I believe you should best contact and ask the organisers/instructors of the courses you are taking the exams for. They are the only people authorized to advise you in this situation. Another person could be someone who acts as a personal tutor to you, although he/she may redirect you

Comment: And cross posted and closed here: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/158004/75821

Answer (score 2):

That is usually covered in the documentation and what the professor decides both prior to and after a situation.